# Windows install disk to ISO file to USB HDD to boot and install Windows on a PC that has no optical drive. Can it be done?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, windows, iso

If I put a Windows install disk in my Ubuntu desktop DVD drive, make an ISO file from it, can I then (somehow) use that ISO file to turn a USB connected HDD into something that will boot and install said Windows onto a PC that lacks an optical drive? I have install disks for Windows 98, ME, XP and 7. I don't care which version I end up with.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a windows problem not an Ubuntu problem. Your answer depends in whether windows allows this.

Comment: As I understand you are doing this in Ubuntu, which makes it an Ubuntu topic. If you extract the DVD to a USB drive, UEFI should boot it. The target USB partition should be formatted FAT32.

Comment: Windows install .iso images are **free** from Microsoft, so the need to extract an old, unsupported version using Ubuntu seems unnecessary.